# Rename files in a directory; new name depends on part of old name

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I want to rename files in a directory whose names match certain suffixes, namely `810` or `814`.  I want the new names to include a string selected depending on the suffix (for `814`, `EB_ENROLL_REQ`; for `810`, `EB_BCHG_REQ`).

Examples of the input filenames (all in `$source_dir`) are:

```
CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI810
CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043407.EDI814
helloworld
CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043487.EDI814
test123
files.txt
CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043467.EDI810
```

I want to read all files in the directory and rename only the files ending with `814` or `810`, ignoring the rest.

I tried:

```
export search_dir=/home/test2

declare -a myArray
myArray[814]=EB_ENROLL_REQ
myArray[810]=EB_BCHG_REQ

for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
    pattern=${entry: -3}
    #if ??
    mv "$entry" "$entry.XHS.JOBRUNID.${myArray[$pattern]}.$entry.XHE"
done
```

but didn't get what I need.

The output filename for an `814` file should be, for example:

```
CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043487.EDI814.XHS.JOBRUNID.EB_ENROLL_REQ.CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043487.EDI814.XHE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare -A myArray                   # -A, not -a --- index by strings
myArray["814"]=EB_ENROLL_REQ         # string suffixes, not numeric
myArray["810"]=EB_BCHG_REQ

cd "$search_dir"       # Otherwise you have to strip $search_dir out of $entry
for entry in *81[04]   # Only work on the files that end with 810 or 814
do
    pattern=${entry: -3}             # the string "810" or "814"
    mv "$entry" "$entry.XHS.JOBRUNID.${myArray[$pattern]}.$entry.XHE"
done
```

Comment: i think i confused with my qs by saying jus part of it. the whole question is i want to add some string based on the suffix 814/810 to the renamed file

Comment: @Rczone Edited - give it a shot! -- **Edited again** to fix a bug I found in testing.

Comment: yeah i declared search_dir=/home/test/ so when i read that it is reading the directory path also

Comment: @Rczone So does the edited script meet your needs?  On my system, it appears to do what you describe in your edited question (if I am understanding the question as you intend).

Comment: @Rczone Glad to hear it!  Would you please hit the checkmark to accept this answer, then?  As you know, that clears the question off the Unanswered lists and we both get reputation points :) .